# Vue.js problems with if statement. Working really wierd

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js, twig

I will show you my problem as simple as it's possible:

**Using:**

Vue.js, TWIG, iCheck (*if that matter*).

**Fields:**

`userEditObj.role` - `["1","2","3"]` *that's from Vue.js*

`kid.id` - `1` *this is from TWIG*

**Problem:**

`${ userEditObj.role.indexOf({{ kid.id }}) > 0 ? true : false }` - working well.

Here I want to set checked attribute of my checkbox depends of the statement result (*true or false*)

`:checked="userEditObj.role.indexOf({{ kid.id }}) > 0 ? true : false"` - it is not working. ALWAYS true.

Also i was trying to do that:

`:checked="userEditObj.role.indexOf({{ kid.id }})"` - same. Always true.

I heared that i can't use mustaches inside HTML attributes, but I can't even find replacement for that.

Comment: not sure if this is your problem, but you should be checking for  `> -1` because if the id is at index 0 you will still get false when its in the array. indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present

Answer (score 0):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the -1 when the index is not found so, checking `> 0` won't work if what you're looking for is the first element in the array. You need `>= 0`.

Using the `? true : false` is redundant as that's what `>= 0` (and `> 0`) would return anyway.

Also, if `kid.id === 1`, this won't work anyway as `1` is an int and `userEditObj.role` is full of strings.

Assuming `kid.id` is an int in twig, you probably need to do something like this:

```
:checked="userEditObj.role.indexOf('{{ kid.id }}') >= 0"
```

The idea is to output `kid.id` as a JS string since the array is filled with string variables.

You may be able to skip the "stringify" step by changing other parts of your code.

```js
let role = ["1", "2", "3"];
let kidId = 1;
let kidIdString = "1";
console.log(role.indexOf(kidId)); // fails. returns -1
console.log(role.indexOf(kidIdString)); // found. returns 0
```

Comment: But there's no longer a problem. The problem is with iCheck lib. When i set timeout on iCheck init then my checkboxes are checked/unchecked correctly. Looks like iCheck fires up before Vue's variables are ready. iCheck is initiated in $(document).ready.

Comment: Cool. If you fixed your code by changing anything, post what you did as an answer to your own question. For future Googlers

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with **iCkeck** lib. Looks like it doesn't refresh checkboxes that was changed by input attribute. I had to destroy iCkeck and fire it up again. Now works.